# What is "black box" testing?

Tags: terminology, testing, dtap

What is "black box" testing and how it is different from ordinary testing? For example black box tests prior to deploying to production.

**Note**: "black box" testing is a common requirement when applying for devops roles (not necessary a tester thing).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to the this question belongs in the Software Quality Assurance & Testing SE, not here

Comment: @Rsf or to http://security.stackexchange.com/ [White-box vs. Black-box](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/214/white-box-vs-black-box)

Comment: Voting to close this, as it is better suited for other SE sites.

Comment: Yes, it can fall under different categories. I think the best approach would be  to send general SQA questions to SQA, and questions where domain knowledge is needed to the relevant SE.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I will make my answer, based on the knowledge for security testing, but IMHO this can be generalized.

- Black box testing - when the tester know nothing about the system, components, liaisons, connections, etc. This can be helpful more like UI/UX testing, functional testing. Example: you do not work for Microsoft and also you do not have the source code and need to test MS Office
- Gray box testing - when the tester have some knowledge about how the system work, some information about internals.
- White box testing - when the tester have or can get all the information about internals, connections, principles of work of the tested product. Example: testing Linux kernel.

For reference:

[Black box testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black-box_testing) (Wikipedia)

[White box testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White-box_testing) (Wikipedia)

[Gray box testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gray_box_testing) (Wikipedia)

Answer (score 2):

As answered by [Romeo Ninov](https://devops.stackexchange.com/users/57/romeo-ninov) in Black Box testing, tester is unaware about the application internal structure.

> This method is named so because the software program, in the eyes of
>   the tester, is like a black box; inside which one cannot see. This
>   method attempts to find errors in the following categories:
>
> - Incorrect or missing functions
> - Interface errors
> - Errors in data structures or external database access
> - Behavior or performance errors
> - Initialization and termination errors

Refrence:

- http://softwaretestingfundamentals.com/black-box-testing/